# Firewall issue for port 25 on Fedora FC15

Tags: iptables, sendmail, fedora

I am trying to test/set up my mail server.  I am currently running into an issue when trying to telnet into my server on port 25.

Here is netstat output for port 25
`# netstat -plnt | grep :25
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      30750/sendmail: acc`

Here is the output of `iptables -L`
[image: iptables output]

I can telnet on the loopback but not from any other computers on the network.
When I try from another computer I get failed connections.  Also the mail server won't receive any email.

However, if I bring down `iptables`, I can telnet in with no problems and my mail server begins to receive mail.
So is there an error in my `iptables` setup?

Comment: Please show your firewall with something like `iptables -n -v -L`. You must use the verbose option to see the entire firewall rules. Also please copy and paste; there's no need for an image here.

Comment: your reject rule is _BEFORE_ accept (smtp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got your accept rule in SMTP *after* your reject rule before the rest of the unmatched traffic.

Basically, your `smtp` and `submission` port will never match due to the order of which you've added them to the IPtables chain.